# ¿Cómo insertar datos de una tabla en HTML en forma de array a MySQL, a través de Ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, array, html-tabla

he estado lidiando con esto hace mucho tiempo, y soy muy novato en el tema.
Tengo una tabla dinámica con productos que necesitan ser enviados hacia la base de datos.
Me gustaría de algún modo enviar toda la tabla `HTML` hacia `MySQL` y no he podido lograrlo.

```html
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tabla1" class="table-bordered table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Cod</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Cod-trans</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Tipo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>7454</td>
      <td>Impresora</td>
      <td>000-432-6456</td>
      <td>2019-10-01</td>
      <td>Articulo1</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7259</td>
      <td>Cartucho AB2</td>
      <td>000-312-3478</td>
      <td>2019-10-02</td>
      <td>Articulo6</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7454</td>
      <td>Impresora</td>
      <td>000-432-6456</td>
      <td>2019-10-01</td>
      <td>Articulo1</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6232</td>
      <td>CartuchoA125</td>
      <td>000-915-9321</td>
      <td>2019-10-01</td>
      <td>Articulo15</td>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input id="btn_enviar" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-primary" value="enviar">

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Doy como ejemplo una tabla sencilla que posee 5 columnas.
¿Cómo puedo crear un array con los datos de esta tabla y que se puedan insertar completamente los datos a `MySQL`? ¿Cómo  puedo enviar esto con Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Planteamiento:

Piensa como si fuera un array bidimiensional. Los elementos `tr` son la primera "dimension" y los elementos `td` son las segunda.
Pensando en eso lo que he hecho ha sido recorrer con **JQuery** cada elemento `tr` de `#tabla1 tbody` y luego en cada `tr` he recorrido los elementos `td` y añadido su texto a un array. Y el array generado se inserta dentro de un array general.

Básicamente, genera un array bidimensional con los datos

#### Solución:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn_enviar").click(function(){
    //Declaramos el array general
    var todo=[];
    //Recorremos cada tr dentro de #tabla1 tbody
    $("#tabla1 tbody tr").each(function(){
        //Declaramos el array de cada línea de la tabla
        var ele=[];
        //Buscamos en el elemento tr cada elemento td
        $(this).find("td").each(function(){
            //Añadimos al array de la tabla el contenido.
            //.text() cojera solo el texto aunque exista dentro html
            ele.push($(this).text());
        });
        //Añadimos el array de la linea al array general
        todo.push(ele);
    });
    console.log(todo);
  });
});
```

Luego en **PHP** solo tienes que recorrer los datos con un bucle dentro de otro

> **IMPORTANTE**: Te has dejado los `<tr>` de `<tbody>` sin cerrar

Comment: Excelente gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, se utiliza los datos de la base de datos para armar la tabla. Ya que la tabla html es la que vas a mostrar finalmente a tu cliente. 
Ahora, a tu respuesta. Si realmente quieres guardar ese html en un campo de base de datos.
Puedes convertir toda la tabla en un string y guardar como cualquier otro dato, asegurate que tu campo sea de tipo text o longtext y listo. 
En jquery el codigo sería así:

```
var tabla1 = $("#tabla1").outerHTML;
```

[jquery.outerHtml](https://plugins.jquery.com/outerHtml/)
Entonces desde ahí ya es cuestión de enviar por ajax.

Comment: Hola Pablo, la tabla lo tengo y traida desde mysql.. sólo lo hice de manera básica para que me ayuden a crear el código para generar el array. ¿ Cómo puedo generar la tabla como un string? estoy hablando de una cantidad de 20 filas. Por eso estoy buscando la forma de generar arrays por columna y así poder enviar con PHP